# Azure container instance run bash command

Tags: azure, containers, azure-container-instances

I am running an R Shiny app inside a container in Azure Container Instance. Via a DevOps pipeline whenever I change the source code of my App, I recreate the container in the Build pipeline and update the Container Instance via an Azure Cli command in the Release pipline via `az container create` and `az container restart`.

After spinning it up I need to run a bash command - namely, automatically adjusting a file within the created container.
In local Docker this would be

```
docker exec {containerName} /bin/bash -c "echo `"var1 = \`"val1`"`" >> /home/shiny/.Renviron"
```

This means: run a bash command in the container to push some text into the `.Renviron` file within the container.

Now the Azure Container Instance says you cannot pass command arguments for `az container exec`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-exec

How would you then in an automated build/release process in Azure go for building, releasing and configuring a container?

I do not want to set those values within the build pipeline as I want to use the same image for different staging areas setting those values accordingly.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very new to azure container instances, so I may not understand your aims but it seems another way of achieving this:

> I do not want to set those values within the build pipeline as I want
>   to use the same image for different staging areas setting those values
>   accordingly.

could be to modify your parameter values upon container creation using the --command-line flag mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create). Something like

```
az container create -g MyResourceGroup --name myapp --image myimage:latest --command-line "/bin/sh -c '/path to/myscript.sh val1 val2'"
```

in which `myscript.sh` runs your app with the indicated values.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, elltrain! We came up with the same idea and will stick to it for the moment.